# сравнить даты в hql запросе

Tags: java, mysql, hibernate, дата, hql

У меня есть таблица в mysql с колонками

```
start_date DATE NOT NULL,
end_date   DATE NOT NULL
```

В java создается объект сущность с полями типа java.util.Date;

```
 @Column(name = "start_date")
    private Date startDate;

 @Column(name = "end_date")
    private Date endDate;
```

в репозитории данного объекта я хочу получить запись которая будет соответствовать условию: startDate <= endDate;
Пытаюсь получать это так:

```
tempBooking = (Booking) session
    .createQuery("FROM Booking where roomId = " + booking.getRoomId() + " and userId = "
        + booking.getUserId() + " and startDate = '"
        + booking.getStartDate()
        + "' and endDate = '"
        + booking.getEndDate()
        + "' and startDate <= endDate")
     .getResultList().stream().findFirst().orElse(null);
```

Конечно же, он не работает. Я думаю это из за того, что формат даты неверный, т.к. Date в java возвращает запись типа Wen Mar 05 00:00:00 MSK 2003 а в таблице значения выглядят так: 2003-03-05
Как мне можно привести значения к общему формату для того чтобы суметь их сравнить?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Не создавайте строку запроса вклеивая в нее аргументы. Это [плохо](https://ru.wikipedia.org/wiki/%D0%92%D0%BD%D0%B5%D0%B4%D1%80%D0%B5%D0%BD%D0%B8%D0%B5_SQL-%D0%BA%D0%BE%D0%B4%D0%B0) и точки зрения безопасности и приводит вот к таким проблемам, когда нужно задумываться о точном представлении даты в виде строки.

Вместо этого используйте именованные параметры:

```
String hql = "FROM Booking where roomId = :roomId and "
        +  "userId = :userId and startDate = :startDate"
        + " and endDate = :endDate"
        + " and startDate <= endDate");
Query query = session.createQuery(hql);

query.setParameter("roomId", booking.getRoomId());
query.setParameter("userId", booking.getUserId());
query.setParameter("startDate", booking.getStartDate());
query.setParameter("endDate", booking.getEndDate());

tempBooking = (Booking)query.getResultList().stream().findFirst().orElse(null);
```